# Задача на Python вход выход данных

Tags: python, python-3.6

Формат входных данных:
Дана строка s длины 2, состоящая из строчных букв английского алфавита и цифр.

Формат выходных данных:
Выведите YES, если она состоит ровно из одной буквы и одной цифры. В противном случае выведите NO.

Примеры:
hq- NO
d2 - YES
2b - YES
31 - NO

Comment: Что у вас не получается? Что вы сами смогли сделать?

Comment: Учебные задания допустимы в качестве вопросов только при условии, что вы пытались решить их самостоятельно перед тем, как задать вопрос. Пожалуйста, отредактируйте вопрос и укажите, что именно вызвало у вас трудности при решении задачи. Например, приведите код, который вы написали, пытаясь решить задачу

Comment: Недавно начал изучение языка. Увидев задачу, решил спросить здесь. В будущем буду задавать вопросы, в соответствии с правилами

Answer (score -1):

Один из вариантов:

```
def check_string(s):
    if len(s) != 2:
        return 'NO'
    if s[0].isdigit() and s[1].isdigit():
        return 'NO'
    if s[0].isalpha() and s[1].isalpha():
        return 'NO'
    return 'YES'

print(check_string('hq')) # NO
print(check_string('d2')) # YES
print(check_string('2b')) # YES
print(check_string('31')) # NO
```